# JSON file to CSV or Oracle Table

Tags: json, xml, oracle

I have to convert a JSON file in a CSV file or even better, extract the JSON file content in to an Oracle table.

I gave a look into the other topics and the only one that I found is related to the conversion in HTML table.

The files are really unstructured, here an example:

```
        {
          "message-version" : "1.2",
          "orcid-profile" : {
            "orcid" : null,
            "orcid-id" : null,
            "orcid-identifier" : {
              "value" : null,
              "uri" : "http://orcid.org/0000-0002-3285-9536",
              "path" : "0000-0002-3285-9536",
              "host" : "orcid.org"
            },
            "orcid-deprecated" : null,
            "orcid-preferences" : {
              "locale" : "EN"
            },
            "orcid-history" : {
              "creation-method" : "MEMBER_REFERRED",
              "completion-date" : null,
              "submission-date" : {
                "value" : 1417193651961
              },
              "last-modified-date" : {
                "value" : 1418131422749
              },
              "claimed" : {
                "value" : true
              },
              "source" : null,
              "deactivation-date" : null,
              "verified-email" : {
                "value" : true
              },
              "verified-primary-email" : {
                "value" : true
              },
              "visibility" : null
            },
            "orcid-bio" : {
              "personal-details" : {
                "given-names" : {
                  "value" : "Marcin"
                },
                "family-name" : {
                  "value" : "Serocki"
                },
                "credit-name" : null,
                "other-names" : null
              },
              "biography" : null,
              "researcher-urls" : null,
              "contact-details" : null,
              "keywords" : null,
              "external-identifiers" : null,
              "delegation" : null,
              "applications" : null,
              "scope" : null
            },
            "orcid-activities" : {
              "affiliations" : {
                "affiliation" : [ {
                  "type" : "EDUCATION",
                  "department-name" : "Department of Pharmaceutical Technology and Biochemistry",
                  "role-title" : "PhD",
                  "start-date" : {
                    "year" : {
                      "value" : "2010"
                    },
                    "month" : {
                      "value" : "09"
                    },
                    "day" : {
                      "value" : "01"
                    }
                  },
                  "end-date" : null,
                  "organization" : {
                    "name" : "Gdansk University of Technology",
                    "address" : {
                      "city" : "Gdansk",
                      "region" : null,
                      "country" : "PL"
                    },
                    "disambiguated-organization" : null
                  },
                  "source" : {
                    "source-orcid" : {
                      "value" : null,
                      "uri" : "http://orcid.org/0000-0002-3285-9536",
                      "path" : "0000-0002-3285-9536",
                      "host" : "orcid.org"
                    },
                    "source-client-id" : null,
                    "source-name" : {
                      "value" : "Marcin Serocki"
                    },
                    "source-date" : {
                      "value" : 1418131402196
                    }
                  },
                  "created-date" : {
                    "value" : 1418131402196
                  },
                  "last-modified-date" : {
                    "value" : 1418131402196
                  },
                  "visibility" : "PUBLIC",
                  "put-code" : "611828"
                }, {
                  "type" : "EDUCATION",
                  "department-name" : "Department of Pharmaceutical Technology and Biochemistry",
                  "role-title" : "MSc",
                  "start-date" : {
                    "year" : {
                      "value" : "2005"
                    },
                    "month" : {
                      "value" : "09"
                    },
                    "day" : {
                      "value" : "01"
                    }
                  },
                  "end-date" : {
                    "year" : {
                      "value" : "2010"
                    },
                    "month" : {
                      "value" : "07"
                    },
                    "day" : {
                      "value" : "01"
                    }
                  },
                  "organization" : {
                    "name" : "Gdansk University of Technology",
                    "address" : {
                      "city" : "Gdansk",
                      "region" : null,
                      "country" : "PL"
                    },
                    "disambiguated-organization" : null
                  },
                  "source" : {
                    "source-orcid" : {
                      "value" : null,
                      "uri" : "http://orcid.org/0000-0002-3285-9536",
                      "path" : "0000-0002-3285-9536",
                      "host" : "orcid.org"
                    },
                    "source-client-id" : null,
                    "source-name" : {
                      "value" : "Marcin Serocki"
                    },
                    "source-date" : {
                      "value" : 1418131329327
                    }
      },
      "created-date" : {
        "value" : 1418131329327
      },
      "last-modified-date" : {
        "value" : 1418131329327
      },
      "visibility" : "PUBLIC",
      "put-code" : "611826"
    } ]
  },
  "orcid-works" : null,
  "funding-list" : null
},
"orcid-internal" : null,
"type" : "USER",
"group-type" : null,
"client-type" : null
   },
   "orcid-search-results" : null,
   "error-desc" : null
 }
```

I have no idea how to proceed?

Answer (score -1):

All code is available at github.
The code is updated according to the changed did in csv in 2013 since then CSVs now have headers! The key name for the field is now the first row of the CSV.

https://github.com/vinay20045/json-to-csv

OR

You can use api

https://json-csv.com/api to convert.

Just register there get api accessibility privileges and use thier code. That's it

Comment: You can import the csv into oracle. As csv can be imported into any database.
 
Load csv into oracle using PL/SQL or SQL statements

Comment: I have a lot of problems running the python script as I'm not expert of Python, there would be another solution? thanks